# Doctrine is not adding new entity in database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been wondering what might be wrong with my code as the new entity is not being added in database by Doctrine2. After running

> doctrine:schema:update --force

I'm having the following returned:

> doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
>   Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
>   doctrine:schema:update --force
>   Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

Here is my new entity:

```
<?php

namespace MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Distributor
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="distributor")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MainBundle\Repository\DistributorRepository")
 */
class Distributor
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="company_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $companyName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="contact_name", type="string")
     */
    private $contactName;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=14, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text")
     */
    private $message;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set companyName
     *
     * @param string $companyName
     *
     * @return Distributor
     */
    public function setCompanyName($companyName)
    {
        $this->companyName = $companyName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get companyName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompanyName()
    {
        return $this->companyName;
    }

    /**
     * Set contactName
     *
     * @param string $contactName
     *
     * @return Distributor
     */
    public function setContactName($contactName)
    {
        $this->contactName = $contactName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contactName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContactName()
    {
        return $this->contactName;
    }


    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Distributor
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     *
     * @return Distributor
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Distributor
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set message
     *
     * @param string $message
     *
     * @return Distributor
     */
    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get message
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}
```

Below is the way my folders are organised:

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Here is the configuration of doctrine in my project:

[image]

Comment: If you go into mysql command in the database and do a `show tables` does the table `distributor` exist already?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Thanks for your answer. No, there is not any table with the same name.

Comment: Firstly try run app/console doctrine:schema:validate and secondly try Doctrine Database Migrations (recommended by documentation). Or try recreate Database and run update again.

Comment: I've just tried recreate the database and run doctrine:schema:update --force command again, but I still have the issue, the entity Distributor being ignored by Doctrine. With doctrine:schema:validate I'm having this confirmation: [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

Comment: Please show your doctrine configuration section in config.yml.

Comment: @Molarro added doctrine configuration on my request.

Comment: @Patrick Bass under "dbal" section try to add "orm" section and under that section add following parameters - auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"; auto_mapping: true. And retry update.

Comment: @Molarro Sorry, I didn't show everything about doctrine configuration, I've edited my main request adding the missing part, which matches what you're asking me to do

Answer (score 0):

I think this line needs to be changed like so:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MainBundle\Entity\DistributorRepository")
```

Also make sure you actually have created the file: `src/MainBundle/Entity/DistributorRepository.php`. Notice the path includes `Entity` not `Repository`! Also, make sure those folder exist.

Here's the reference documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html

Comment: I have added a picture to show how my folders are organised.

Comment: I wonder if you have symfony2 version prior to 2.7? Use the command `symfony |less` to see what information that shows? If so, you might to upgrade to either 2.7 or 2.8. Otherwise, I'm at a loss at what could be wrong.

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.8.6

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this issue after I tried a bunch of things. I believe the effective tip was adding the file Resources/config/doctrine/Distributor.orm.yml. Now the command

> doctrine:schema:update --force

has now allowed me to add the table "distributor" in the datatabase. Thank you all out there for your input.